# Jade thinking mixin is undefined, but it's not

Tags: templates, pug

Why this doesn't work?

```
extends layout

mixin WhyNotDefined(text)
  p #{text}

append content
  mixin WhyNotDefined('Hi')
```

I keep getting error: `WhyNotDefined_mixin is not defined`

jade@0.20.3; node v0.6.14

**upd.**

Stupid of me, mixins should be defined in block. This works:

```
extends layout

append content
  mixin WhyNotDefined(text)
    p #{text}

  mixin WhyNotDefined('Hi')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid of me, mixins should be defined in block. This works:

```
extends layout

append content
  mixin WhyNotDefined(text)
    p #{text}

  mixin WhyNotDefined('Hi')
```